# Windows Live Mesh offers sync for program settings; can I add support for my software?

Tags: api, plugins

Is there a way I can add support for syncing my program's settings with Windows Live Mesh, so that it would appear in the list below?

[image: windows live mesh]

That's where I would like to see my program offering to "Turn on syncing for your settings". Is there some sort of a plugin API for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Microsoft struggled with opening this thing up to developers, and I believe something similar actually was available for some time during the old Mesh beta days (before they renamed Sync to Mesh). I doubt they will ever allow it since Mesh is being replaced with SkyDrive (I'm pretty sure they actually announced it, but I can't find where, but this basically says the same: http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/is-microsofts-live-mesh-on-its-way-to-the-graveyard/12540). Setting syncing like you want is available to Windows 8 Metro apps through Skydrive and Microsoft Account/Live ID roaming (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/26/signing-in-to-windows-8-with-a-windows-live-id.aspx and  API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingfolder.aspx)
But of course, in exchange for that you restrict your audience to Windows 8 users.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that announcement. What a shame; the only usable sync tool out there is being killed off. Nobody else offers direct sync (without online storage), proper sharing of specific folders with other users, and the actual succeeding at keeping things in sync.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still using Mesh because I need to be able to sync more than one folder. I honestly thought Mesh beta with the live desktop was best. As for actually solving your issue, you could make it work with the [Skydrive API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826521) and store a settings file (encrypted if needed) on the user's Skydrive account, but that would be more work.